# update cell if data is present in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation, vba

Say there are two Worksheet: Worksheet 1 , Worksheet 2

Worksheet 1 has a Column called `'Number'`

Worksheet 2 also also a Column called `'Number'`

Now i am entering a number in the 'Number' column of Worksheet 2.

I now need the Number i entered in Column 'Number' of Worksheet 1 to be matched against 'Number' column of worksheet 1.

If there is a match then allow the entry on Worksheet 2 or else throw an error `'Invalid Data'`.

- The 'Number' column of worksheet 2 should not allow duplicated.

Can you guys please solve the same for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use VBA. You could use **[Data validation:](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx)**

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

Select entire column *"Numbers"* in **sheet2**. go to *Data->Data validation*. Select *Custom* and enter formula:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)),COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)<2)
```

where `Sheet1!$A:$A` address of column "Numbers" in **sheet1**. `$A:$A` - address of column "Numbers" in **sheet2**.

- Part `ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1,Sheet1!$A:$A,0))` allow to enter values only
  from sheet1.
- Part `COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)<2` doesn't allow duplicates

[image]

Select *"Error Alert"* tab and enter error message.

[image]

**Done!**

Comment: You are welcome:) If you have some additional question - ask please:)

Comment: Absolutely! I have a question on copying data from one worksheet to another. I have done a little bit of coding but cant figure out the difficult bit. I'll open a new question and tag you :)

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TarColumn as Integer 'stores the column number of the modified cell
    TarColumn = Target.Column 'sets the column number

    If TarColumn = 1 Then 'replace 1 with the column number of your Number Column
        Dim RowCountA as Long 'stores the amount of rows in your worksheets
        Dim RowCountB as Long
        Dim a, b 'will store the numbers from the number columns

        RowCountA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row of data
        RowCountB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
        a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Resize(RowCountA,1) 'copys the numbers into the arrays
        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,1).Resize(RowCountB,1)

        For i = 0 To RowCountA - 1 'checks to see if it is in the first sheet
            If Target.Value = a(i,1) then
                MsgBox("Invalid Data")
                Target.Value = ""
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

        For i = 0 to RowCountB - 2 'ensures no duplication in the second sheet
            If Target.Value = b(i,1) then
                MsgBox("Invalid Data")
                Target.Value = ""
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

You might need to modify the `.cells(1,1)` to fit your code depending on headers and location in the sheet.

Comment: Thanks Simoco and JRLambert. Both solutions work like a treat. Genuis!! :)